# Python tuple error when working with 2d lists in a quiz program

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have been working on a simple quiz program with a 2d list to store questions and answers in, and have been getting an error "builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" with my code.

Here is my code:

```
import random 

score = 0
incorrect_answers = 0 

Questions_List = [["ANAGRAM 1: 'Agnamar'. Please enter your answer: ", 
"anagram"], ["ANAGRAM 2: 'Coterump'. Please enter your answer: ", 
"computer"], ["ANAGRAM 3: Certcor. Please enter your answer: ", "correct"], 
["ANAGRAM 4: Bleat. Please enter your answer: ", "table"]] 

random.shuffle(Questions_List) 

def answer (Questions_List, score):
    answer = input(Questions_List[score, 0]).lower()
    return answer

while score > 10:
    answer = input(Questions_List, score)

if answer == Questions_List[score, 1]:
    print ("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
elif answer != Questions_List[score, 1]:
    print ("Incorrect!")
    incorrect_answers = incorrect_answers + 1
```

The

```
if answer == Questions_List[score, 1]:
```

line is getting this error, what is the problem?

Comment: Just write `Questions_List[score][1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 

score = 0
incorrect_answers = 0 

Questions_List = [["ANAGRAM 1: 'Agnamar'. Please enter your answer: ", 
"anagram"], ["ANAGRAM 2: 'Coterump'. Please enter your answer: ", 
"computer"], ["ANAGRAM 3: Certcor. Please enter your answer: ", "correct"], 
["ANAGRAM 4: Bleat. Please enter your answer: ", "table"]] 

random.shuffle(Questions_List) 

def answer (Questions_List, score):
    answer = input(Questions_List[score][0]).lower()
    return answer

while score > 10:
    answer = input(Questions_List, score)

if answer == Questions_List[score][1]:
    print ("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
elif answer != Questions_List[score][1]:
    print ("Incorrect!")
    incorrect_answers = incorrect_answers + 1
```

should rectify your problem

A better way to implement it would be:

```
import random 

score = 0
incorrect_answers = 0 

Questions_List = [["ANAGRAM 1: 'Agnamar'. Please enter your answer: ", 
"anagram"], ["ANAGRAM 2: 'Coterump'. Please enter your answer: ", 
"computer"], ["ANAGRAM 3: Certcor. Please enter your answer: ", "correct"], 
["ANAGRAM 4: Bleat. Please enter your answer: ", "table"]] 

random.shuffle(Questions_List) 
#print(Questions_List)

for i in range(0,len(Questions_List)):
  answer = input(Questions_List[i][0])
  if answer == Questions_List[i][1]:
    print("Correct!")
    score += 1
  else:
    incorrect_answers += 1
    print("Let's try again")
    continue

print("Your final score is: ",score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way:

```
import random 

score = 0
incorrect_answers = 0 

Questions_List = [["ANAGRAM 1: 'Agnamar'. Please enter your answer: ", 
"anagram"], ["ANAGRAM 2: 'Coterump'. Please enter your answer: ", 
"computer"], ["ANAGRAM 3: Certcor. Please enter your answer: ", "correct"], 
["ANAGRAM 4: Bleat. Please enter your answer: ", "table"]] 

random.shuffle(Questions_List) 

def answer (Questions_List, score):
    answer = input(Questions_List[score][0]).lower()
    return answer

while (score-incorrect_answers)<len(Questions_List):
   a = answer(Questions_List, score)
   if a == Questions_List[score][1]:
       print ("Correct!")
       score+=1
   elif a != Questions_List[score][1]:
       print ("Incorrect!")
       incorrect_answers+=1
```